# div заходит под по div c position fixed

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить, чтобы `div` с `id="footer"` не заходил под `div` с `id="header"`.

```css
#header{height:100px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); width:100%;opacity:0.8;position: fixed;}
#footer{height:200px;background: #e0001a; width:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 
</div>
<div id="footer">
 
</div>
```

Comment: пробивали через `margin-top:`?

Comment: @Микола Кікець После div с `id="header"` и перед div с `id="footer"` находится еще информация (причём динамическая), маргином это вообще не вариант.

Comment: А что футер должен делать вместо того, чтобы не заходить под шапку? Залезать на шапку сверху?

Comment: если размеры шапки динамические, то тут без `JS` никак)

Comment: скажите а для чего нужно ставить `header` как `fixed`?

Comment: @МиколаКікець Загляните в документацию для чего необходим fixed. Фиксированное меню на сайте. [Документация](https://webref.ru/course/positioning/position)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю надо делать `padding-top` у `body`, высотой в `#header`. 
При наличии контента на сайте подвал до шапки не достанет.

```css
body { padding-top: 100px }
#header{height:100px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); width:100%;opacity:0.8;position: fixed; top: 0 }
#footer{height:200px;background: #e0001a; width:100%;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
 
</div>
<div id="footer">
 
</div>
```

Comment: @ Отлично! Спасибо большое!:)